# Capybara returns hidden elements when using Poltergeist?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I'm using the following Capybara query:

```
all(:xpath, '//table[@class="myClass"]//tr)
```

My table contains two entries:

```
<tr class="class1" style="visibility: hidden;">
<tr class="class2">
```

The code above is a bit simplified compared to the original, but It serves the example. When running Capybara against Chrome or Firefox, the query results one element (class2). When running the same code against Poltergeist, I'm getting both elements. I tried to play around with explicitly telling Capybara to ignore hidden elements, but I'm still getting the hidden one. Am I'm missing here something?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @Pablo Not really. What I do is manually filter 'class1' (like in the above example) using xPath like so: `all(:xpath, '//table[@class="myClass"]//tr[not(@class="class1")])`. This of-course not always possible.

Comment: IIRC all returns all elements unless you specify `visible: true`

Comment: `all(:xpath, '//table[@class="myClass"]//tr', visible: true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by the Poltergeist team:
https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/618#issuecomment-150139228